# start after task finish but must end as finish to finish to another task

Tags: ms-project, dependencies

I have task B which cant start until task A is finished (FS) but must end with task C end date (FF)(i.e. duration of B might be floating depending on the end of task A and end of task C) .. is this achievable on msproject?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you may need a "Hammock" task, which is something that I asked about some time ago on this site. The original question (and associated answers) are here: [In MS Project, can I create a task whose duration depends on two milestones?](https://pm.stackexchange.com/questions/9168/in-ms-project-can-i-create-a-task-whose-duration-depends-on-two-milestones/9169#9169) .